# How to scroll to element in Angular?

Tags: angular

I use Angular >= 9, and I have a HostListener to listen to `arrowdown` and `arrowup` events. See the simplified code below:

```
@HostListener('window:keydown.arrowup', ['$event'])
onArrowDown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.selected--;
}

@HostListener('window:keydown.arrowdown', ['$event'])
onArrowDown($event: KeyboardEvent) {
    this.selected++;
}
```

In the HTML template I have a list and check if `selected == i` to indicate that this is the element I just selected. However, if the list is too long, an `arrowdown` does not scroll (of course) to that element.

```html
<div *ngFor="let o of objects; let i = index" [attr.data-index]="i">
IsSelected: {{selected == i}}
</div>
```

Since `selected++` or `selected--` triggers an UI update afterwards, i can't use the `scrollTo` function right after. What would be a proper solution to this issue?

Comment: Why can you not scroll immediately after changing the value of `selected`? All of the elements are in the DOM are they not?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the UI update is causing the `ngFor` to recreate the DOM. If you use the `trackBy` function like:

```html
<div *ngFor="let o of objects; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFunction" [attr.data-index]="i">
IsSelected: {{selected == i}}
</div>
```

```js
function trackByFunction(object: ?) {
  return object.id; // or something that uniquely identifies the object.
}
```

Then you should be able to scroll immediately after changing the value of `selected`.